# What exactly does nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1 mean in minikube annotation?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

While working with minikube ingress, I have to write `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1`. I have been trying hard to understand why we need this annotation and how to use it.

I know that the [doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite) says the following:

> In some scenarios the exposed URL in the backend service differs from the specified path in the Ingress rule. Without a rewrite any request will return 404. Set the annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target to the path expected by the service.

But I am not able to get the exact point of what exactly `the exposed URL in the backend service differs from the specified path in the Ingress rule` means. I am not able to get the idea clearly.

Further, upon trying to execute ingress file with services:

code 1:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  namespace: example-namespace
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myexample.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix 
            backend:
              service:
                name: example-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

code 2:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  namespace: example-namespace
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myexample.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix 
            backend:
              service:
                name: example-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

code 3:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  namespace: example-namespace
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myexample.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /index
            pathType: Prefix 
            backend:
              service:
                name: example-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

what exactly is the difference between each pair of the above 3 code snippets with respect to rewrite-target and path mentioned above?

PS: I'm new to minikube and trying to figure out the exact way things work. Please help.

Answer (score 20):

I don't know if things changes with new versions of the Ingress resource or with new versions of the Nginx Ingress Controller, but this is how I think it works.

Suppose I want to serve 2 different web applications under the same domain, with a Ingress.

- App A is expecting requests under `/`
- App B is expecting requests under `/`

So, both Apps are expecting their requests directly under root, which (at first glance) seems to make them impossible to be served at the same domain.

Except, with rewrite targets, I can. I could just serve them under a different path, but rewrite the target to `/`

- Serve App A under `myexample.com/aaa/`
- Serve App B under `myexample.com/bbb/`

And add a rewrite target to remove the first part of the path. This is just an example of what a rewrite target can be used for, it simply makes you able to serve an application under a different path of the one expected by the app itself.

Example of the ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  namespace: example-namespace
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myexample.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /aaa(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix 
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-a
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /bbb(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix 
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-b
                port:
                  number: 80
```

**Notice that**, while this works pretty well on Rest API and similar things, it may work less well on web pages, because a web page could try to load resources at a different path (for example if it does not use relative paths). This is why (usually) frontend applications needs to know on which path they are being served under a domain.

---

Regarding the syntax of rewrite targets, I'll take as example the Ingress I wrote above. There are a couple things to take into consideration:

- path
- pathType
- rewrite-target

Let's start with `path` and `pathType` interactions. With the path I can define where to serve my services. Depending on the `pathType`, it may be just a `Prefix` of the whole path, the `Exact` path, or it can depends on the Ingress Controller (aka `ImplementationSpecific`). Everything is nicely explain in the documentation with a long table of examples ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples )

I can do almost everything just with path and pathType, except if the applications I want to serve are expecting to be served at different paths from the ones specified in the Ingress; this is when `rewrite-target` comes into play.

Like in the example above, I can use `rewrite-target` to serve an application under a different path from the one expected, composing the url as I want. I can also use regex and capture groups (this is what `$1`, `$2` and so on are)

For example, if I write `path: /bbb(/|$)(.*)` I mean that this path will match everything under /bbb, with or without a / after bbb. And if I then write `rewrite-target: /$2` I'm meaning that requests will be rewritten to substitute `/bbb` with `/` and then take the second capture group (which means the second regex expression, `(.*)` )

The documentation explains it pretty well, even if it makes still use of the old Ingress resource ( https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/ )

Comment: just a small note about the changed behaviour since version 0.22 https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md#rewrite-target

Answer (score 3):

Great explanation provided by [@AndD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11970424/andd)!

There are few things I'd like to add:

- the `(/|$)(.*)` is sometimes crucial as you want to reach your app under https://example.com and https://example.com/
- nginx-ingress is an NGINX tailored to work on, and managed by, Kubernetes, so all the [NGINX documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) regarding proxying does apply
- The `$1` and `$2` variables capture the path elements that aren't changing, [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#directives)

So here's how I'd do it (main service under `/` pathType (Prefix) and all sub-paths excluding the `/test` pathType (Exact) to point to testing service):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-dev
  namespace: develop
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-test-svc
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /test(.*)
        pathType: Exact
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-main-svc
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
```